# Data Creation from spreadsheet for Parameterized Junit Test

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have written a test class with a few of test cases inside it using Selenium Junit. I need to run these tests based on the configuration values stored in a spread sheet. Could some one please help me how to write parameterized junit cases which can execute tests based on the values in spreadsheet.

I am trying as below but still no luck,

Could you please provide me a sample example in which a test is executed based on the data stored in a file (spreadsheet).

```
@Parameters
         public  static Collection read_config() throws Exception
         {           
                String file_path;
                String s3;
                Sheet s;
                ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                ....                
                ....


                       /*return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {

                              });*/
                  }


                //}      





         }


public myTest (ArrayList<String> list) {
             ....
```

Comment: There really isn't much to go on in your question.  You have to use a library to read the Excel spreadsheet and extract data. Have you investigated [POI](http://poi.apache.org)?

Comment: I am able to read Excel spreadsheet using jxl package and have required data in string but I ma not sure how to write metho with @Parameter Annotations.

Comment: Below is my String which contains actual data

Comment: String[] tempNames1 = new String(tempNames[i]).split(",");

Comment: Not sure how to get data as Collection<Object[]